# Translating Matlab "fit" to R

Tags: r, matlab, regression, data-fitting

Matlab has what appears to be a flexible fitting function call 'fit'
For instance, I can do easily fit a few different models to this data in Matlab:

```
A = [2:40]'; 
B = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,...
                 1,1,2,2,3,3,3,...
                 3,3,4,4,5,5,2,...
                 2,2,2,2,3,3,4,...
                 2,2,3,4,2,3,3,...
                 2,3,2,2]';

M1= fit(A, B, 'exp1');
M2 = fit(A, B, 'gauss1');
M3 = fit(A, B, 'linearinterp');
```

And then apply that mode to vectors and data frames:

```
TT = 3*ones(4,50)

New = reshape(M3(TT),size(TT))

New2 = M1(TT)
```

I've tried to replicate the above two "New" results in R using 'predict' and 'approx' based on results of 'lm', but have failed. What is the best way to go about re-coding the above in R?

Comment: Look into `glm` and its `family=` argument, where [`family=Gamma(link="log")` might resemble Matlab's 'exp1'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085305/6574038) and `family=gaussian()` `'exp1'`.